# Remplazo de un backslash por doble backslash pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy intentando hacer un código que lea un CSV y me reeplace cada string con \ por \, pero el código no me deja seleccionar un backslash para reemplazo, ya que me sale error en las comillas y me detecta como si estuvieran abiertas.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep='|', header=None, error_bad_lines=False)

df = df.replace('\','\\')

df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

Esta es la forma que tiene Python para que le puedas indicar que esa comilla es parte de la cadena. Ejemplo:

```
"hola \"mundo\""
```

De ahí viene el fallo, ya que lo que sigue a la comilla escapada será considerado parte del string original.

#### Solución

Escapa las barras usando... barras! ya que estas tienen un significado especial cuando están junto a ciertos caracteres. Las comillas se pueden seguir escapando incluso colocando r al principio del string, lo cual anula todos los demas significados especiales.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([r"hola \ mundo", r"hola \\ mundo"])

df[0] = df[0].str.replace("\\", "\\\\", regex=False)

print(df)
```

Por cierto, me tomé el trabajo de cambiar el método `replace` por `.str.replace`, ya que ambos métodos no hacen lo mismo (replace es más complejo).

También pasé el argumento regex=False para que no tome las cadenas como regex.

#### Referencias

- [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)